# The restriction $f|_A$ of $f$ to $A$ is a continuous function from the metric space $(A,d)$ to $(Y,d)$.

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $f : (X,d) \to (Y,d)$ be continuous. let $A \subset X$ be open. Show that the restriction $f|_A$ of $f$ to $A$ is a continuous function from the metric space $(A,d)$ to $(Y,d)$.

Please Help I am finding difficulty in doing the problem!!

Answer (score 0):

Let $g=f\mid_A$. Let $V\subset Y$ be open. Since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(V)=U$ (say) is open in $X$. Now $g^{-1}(V)=f^{-1}(V)\cap A=U\cap A$ is open in $A$. Hence inverse image of each open set in $Y$ is open in $A$ under $g$. Hence $g:(A,d)\to (Y,d)$ is continuous.